# What do you call a queue when the word queue is reserved?

Tags: naming

I'm working on a rails app, and in rails `queue` is a reserved word. I need to make a Queue model for my app, and I'm stuck because I don't know what else to call it.

Has anyone else run into this before, and if so what did you call your Queue that can't be called a Queue?

Comment: ....QueueModel?

Comment: In situations like this, a misspelling is accepted as a reasonable practice: the default JVM implementation uses `Klass` as the C++ class name for a Java class.

Comment: ^ This I like, because I will be able to remember it. I'm going to go with `Kueue`, lol.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If this is not a priority queue<sup>*</sup>, you can call it `FIFO`, for the [abbreviated name of the strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) used by the data structure.

---

<sup>*</sup> If it is a priority queue, calling it `priorityQueue` would be a good choice, and it wouldn't conflict with the reserved word

Comment: Good call, I was thinking QueueList or something else ridiculous, fifo makes far more sense.

Comment: _Pipe_, although Queue and FIFO is more commonly used, I think.

Comment: I think the idea in the comments (of intentionally misspelling) will be easier for me to remember in the specific context I'm working in, but this is a really good suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Or add the type of things you plan on storing in it: taskQueue, messageQueue.